# HAProxy backend with different path prefix per server

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

Is it possible to configure an HAProxy backend with multiple servers and different path prefix for each server? I want something like this:

```
backend mybackend
    server node1 server1.example.com/ONE_PATH/%[path]
    server node2 server2.example.com/ANOTHER_PATH/%[path]
```

However the `server` directive does not support specifying a path, only a host and port.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420303/haproxy-add-path-to-backend-server asks this question, but only for one backend server. The answer there is to use `http-request set-path`, but that is per-backend, not per-server, and as I understand there is no way to know which server the request will be sent to at the time the `http-request set-path` is run.

[HAProxy Per server URL rewriting in the backend (reqirep?)](https://serverfault.com/questions/189916/haproxy-per-server-url-rewriting-in-the-backend-reqirep) also asks something similar, and the answer is "not possible", but that was in 2010 and I'm not looking to do arbitrary URL rewriting - just a fixed path prefix per server.